# DNS error: Missing nameservers reported by parent & NSs have same SOA serial

Tags: domain-name-system, wordpress, web-hosting

Newbie here. Been going back and forth between my developer and hosting to fix DNS errors.

Domain name: rmsglobal.co.in
Bought this domain from www.name.com
Hosting site: www.hostingraja.in
Recently asked a freelancer to develop the website and now this issue pops up.

I tried ipconfig/flushDNS and it works
Proxy site also works.

But when I asked a friend overseas to try out the website it shows the same DNS error.
Please advise where exactly the issue lies? What to do?

Comment: Please post your current DNS configuration so it can be compared against what is reported by DNS records.

Comment: You have what appears to be two different sets of name servers. Try picking one set and deleting the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for mentioning your actual domain name.

The WHOIS record shows **4** different name servers configured for your domain:

```
Domain ID:D414400000002066196-AFIN
Domain Name:RMSGLOBAL.CO.IN
Created On:06-Oct-2016 18:59:29 UTC
Last Updated On:14-Oct-2016 14:12:02 UTC
Expiration Date:06-Oct-2018 18:59:29 UTC
Sponsoring Registrar:Name.com LLC (R65-AFIN)
...
Name Server:NS4BTY.NAME.COM
Name Server:NS3CKL.NAME.COM
Name Server:NS65.HOSTINGRAJA.IN
Name Server:NS66.HOSTINGRAJA.IN
DNSSEC:Unsigned
```

When you query each of those name servers for their SOA records you see something interesting:

```
Nameserver NS4BTY.NAME.COM has SOA:      ns1gmz.name.com. support.name.com. 1 10800 3600 604800 300
Nameserver NS3CKL.NAME.COM has SOA:      ns1gmz.name.com. support.name.com. 1 10800 3600 604800 300
Nameserver NS65.HOSTINGRAJA.IN has SOA:  ns65.hostingraja.in. serveralerts.hostingaraja.gmail.com. 2016110100 3600 7200 1209600 86400
Nameserver NS66.HOSTINGRAJA.IN has SOA:  ns65.hostingraja.in. serveralerts.hostingaraja.gmail.com. 2016110100 3600 7200 1209600 86400
```

Rather than all four showing identical information, the behaviour you see is that of two pairs. That looks like somebody tried to **update your name servers** with  new name servers **to replace** the ones from Name.com, instead they **added** two additional ones.

Then they updated the zone on the HOSTINGRAJA.IN name servers and (among others) created a www record for your domain, that doesn't exist on the Name.com name servers. The result is "random" DNS errors.

The solution is to:

- either update your domain registration and remove the two incorrect name servers.
- or ensure that all name servers have the same zone data.

Comment: Awesome. That really helped!